# Flutter Provider Package: error could not find correct Provider<Client> above this LoginForm

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am fairly new to flutter and a bit confused right, my app has been working fine so far up to this point and I have had no trouble with the provider package, now I keep getting an error stating 'Could not find the correct Provider Client above this LoginForm Widget.' I have wrapped my MaterialApp in a MultiProvider class with the providers I want to use for my app. Here is the code for that

'''

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Coach(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) =>
              Authentication(FirebaseAuth.instance, FirebaseFirestore.instance),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Client(),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (ctx) => context.read<Authentication>().authStateChanges,
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: Strings.appName,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (ctx) => AuthenticationWrapper(),
        },
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) => AuthenticationWrapper(),
          );
        },
        onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (ctx) => AuthenticationWrapper(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    final authentication = Provider.of<Authentication>(context);
    if (firebaseUser != null && authentication.showHomeScreen) {
      if (authentication.isCoach) {
        return CoachHomeScreen();
      } else {
        return ClientTabsScreen();
      }
    } else {
      return AuthenticationScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

'''

The Authentication Screen then creates a login form widget which I attempt to access the 'Clients' Provider but it gives me the error that I mentioned above. As I said the app has given me no issues before and the provider had been working fine until this point.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The error essentially means that you are trying to access a Provider instance that you have not defined before you are attempting to use it. Are you sure all your providers have been listed under MultiProvider? Is there any stacktrace that you can paste?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type for each of your providers.

for example, instead of

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Coach(),
        ),
```

write

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<Coach>(
          create: (ctx) => Coach(),
        ),
```